# Loop request Database vs lookup

Tags: php, mongodb, architecture

i have a issue and it make so headache lately. So i need your help.

I have 2 collections: *Customers(A)* and *their history payments(B)*. Now i need to get all data from **A** and map it to **B** by customer_id then show it as report. Example data of **A** is 100,000 and **B** is 500,000.

So should i use lookup to map it and return data to my code:

```
$customer_payments = $mongo_db->aggregate_pipeline('Customers',
    array(
        '$lookup' => array(
            'from' => 'payment_history',
            'localField' => 'customer_id',
            'foreignField' => 'id',
            'as' => 'payment_info',
        ),
    )
);
```

or i read all **A** data and loop it then read one by one to database to get **B** data and map it?

```
$customers = $mongo_db->get('Customers');
foreach ($customers as $key => $cus) {
    $payment_info = $mongo_db->where('customer_id', $cus['id'])->get('payment_history');
    $cus['payment_info'] = $payment_info;
}
```

I use PHP and MongoDB.
My leader told me not use lookup but read one by one -_-.

After all which one is better for me and performance of server?

Comment: I think you have the makings of a good question, but as written it is asking for an opinion. This makes it off-topic.  To make it on topic, show some example code and ask and ask how to do it or ask if there are any issues with the approach.

Comment: I also don’t know exactly what you mean by “use lookup to map it” vs “loop and read one by one”. Sounds to me like you just need a better query.

Comment: Thanks for your thought, i will edit my questions to make it more understandable and become on topic

Comment: I think I understand. Disclaimer: I don’t know mongoDB, nor do I know this wrapper object `$mongo_db`.  But I can let you see it through the eyes of someone who might have to maintain the code after you. Of the two approaches, the latter is more intuitive to me simply because the naming of the methods is more like sql. It is also presumably less efficient, since you’re generating the overhead of a database call for every iteration. For the average web page, this is negligible; but if the size gets too big it would need optimization. The former query, OTOH, presumably joins the tables ...

Comment: together and would be far more efficient and more scalable. The only downside is the naming of the method sucks and makes you have to think about what it’s doing. I understood it from the context of your question, but the array that’s fed into it has rules that aren’t immediately obvious.

Comment: Thanks alot for your thought @TimMorton, i will read your message carefully to improve my coding skills.

Answer (score 1):

**Definitely $lookup**

In you case, MongoDB performs a left outer join two collections by indexed field in very short time and efficient way. Also, you can continue pipeline stage with `payment_info`.

Manually iterating records is extremally ineficient (100.000 queries in `payment_history` will cost PHP / MongoDB hours...).

Comment: I also think the first approaches is better than the second. But my leader dont agree and told me use the second hmm. Btw thanks for your thought.